# Unable to create Nextjs PWA setup

Tags: reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps

I am creating a setup for Next.js PWA but its not wokring. I have tried with

1. Created `manifest.json` and other `icons` inside `public` folder.
2. Created `_document.js` inside `src/pages` with below text

   import Document, {
   Html,
   Head,
   Main,
   NextScript,
   } from 'next/document'

   class MyDocument extends Document {
   render() {
   return (












   )
   }
   }

   export default MyDocument
3. Updated `next.config` file with

   ```
        const withPWA = require('next-pwa')({
      dest: 'public',
      register: true,
      skipWaiting: true,
      disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    })
    /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
    const nextConfig = {
      reactStrictMode: true
    }

    module.exports = withPWA(nextConfig)
   ```
4. Created fresh build but still browser not showing download icon. Note sure what is missed ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in selecting `src` folder. Working file location `/pages/_document.js` but if we put pages folder inside `src` fodler like `/src/pages/_document.js` then it does not works.